Spring Boot 3 Java record RequestBody camel case not filled properly
Since updating to Spring Boot 3, Java record RequestBody behaves strangely.
While this is filled properly from json request:
public record ExampleRequestDto(@JsonProperty("exampleData") String exampleData) {
}

This is not filled and exampleData is null:
public record ExampleRequestDto(String exampleData) {
}

Changing to snake-case also works and example_data is filled properly from request json.
public record ExampleRequestDto(String example_data) {
}

Request record is used in this controller method:
@PostMapping("/example/cancel")
public ResponseEntity<Void> exampleCancel(@RequestBody final ExampleRequestDto request) {
...
}

Before on Spring Boot 2, both worked exactly the same. Is there any configuration that might cause this problem?

You did ofcourse read the upgrade notes on Spring itself. Make sure you are compiling with parameters enabled else binding won't work.

I already have that in my build.gradle:
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {         options.encoding = "UTF-8"         options.compilerArgs.add("-parameters")     }

There is also an update of Jackson involved, which might have different defaults.
